# Show chord diagram by connecting many lines instead of one single

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, chord-diagram

I followed the steps at https://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/ to create a chord diagram.

https://plnkr.co/edit/gmyhqOjphE8EreXKmZMB

How can I create multiple lines connecting two sides?

For example, in the new.json file, if the number of years is 10, then I would need to draw 10 lines connecting LD1 and 10.215.16.0 instead of one single line.

```
function drawChords (matrix, mmap) {
    var w = 980, h = 800, r1 = h / 2, r0 = r1 - 100;

    var fill = d3.scale.category10();

    var chord = d3.layout.chord()
        .padding(.02)
        .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
        .sortChords(d3.descending);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(r0)
        .outerRadius(r0 + 20);

    var svg = d3.select("#diagram").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
      .append("svg:g")
        .attr("id", "circle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

        svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r", r0 + 20);

    var rdr = chordRdr(matrix, mmap);
    chord.matrix(matrix);

    var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
        .data(chord.groups())
      .enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "group")
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", function (d) { d3.select("#tooltip").style("visibility", "hidden") });

    g.append("svg:path")
        .style("stroke", "none")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
        .attr("d", arc);

    g.append("svg:text")
        .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
              + "translate(" + (r0 + 26) + ")"
              + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
        })
        .text(function(d) { return rdr(d).gname; });

      var chordPaths = svg.selectAll("path.chord")
            .data(chord.chords())
          .enter().append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "chord")
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.target.index)).darker(); })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.target.index); })
            .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(r0))
            .on("mouseover", function (d) {
              d3.select("#tooltip")
                .style("visibility", "visible")
                .html(chordTip(rdr(d)))
                .style("top", function () { return (d3.event.pageY - 100)+"px"})
                .style("left", function () { return (d3.event.pageX - 100)+"px";})
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (d) { d3.select("#tooltip").style("visibility", "hidden") });

      function chordTip (d) {
        var p = d3.format(".0%"), q = d3.format("0d")
        return "Chord info:<br/>"
          + q(d.svalue) + " years overlap with " + d.sname + " and " + d.tname
      }

      function groupTip (d) {
        var guru = d.gname, q = d3.format("0d");            
      }

      function mouseover(d, i) {
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("visibility", "visible")
          .html(groupTip(rdr(d)))
          .style("top", function () { return (d3.event.pageY - 80)+"px"})
          .style("left", function () { return (d3.event.pageX - 130)+"px";})

        chordPaths.classed("fade", function(p) {
          return p.source.index != i
              && p.target.index != i;
        });
      }
  }
```